# Failed to open document in QlikView

Tags: qlikview

I have problem with opening a QlikView report.
I did a document in QlikView and then I closed it, now when I try open it again this message appeared:
" DOCUMENT X.qvw failed load"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9LND.png)

Does anyone know what cause such a problem and what I can do to open my file ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Try this.



 Open QlikView Application -> Help -> About QlikView -> Left side bottom you will see QlikView logo, right click on the logo, a new window will open.



 Here find the variable called "ApplicationRescue" click on that, set the value 1 and click on set.



 Close qlikview and then try to open your corrupted qlikview application.
```

Answer (score 1):

This happen when you do not have a QV licence and you tried to open the QVW file in another computer. If this is your scenario, it's not possible to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If your running this on a server, move it to Local and try to open it with a different DocCal (if available).

It might be that your missing the original config file if it's moved location for example.